# How to use express-validator with koa framework?

Tags: koa, express-validator, koa-router

I have built a simple koa app. Would like to use express-validator to validate the incoming API requests for post call. But Getting a failure message when starting the application:

```
TypeError: controller.validatee is not a function\n    at routes 
    (c:\\Users\\XXX\\gjit\\koa-proj\\src\\main\\middlewares\\route- 
   path.js:34:51)\n    at init (c:\\Users\\XXX\\gjit\\koa-proj\\app.js:36:6)\n    
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)'
```

Below is my source code in the order of execution:

```
server.js
const app = require("./app.js");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`));
```

```
app.js
const app = new koa();
const middleware = require("./src/main/middlewares/middlewares");
const routes = require("./src/main/middlewares/route-path");
const init = async () => {
  try {
    /*** Step 2: load endpoint routes for the application*/
     routes(router)
     app.use(router.routes())
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({
      err
    });
  }
};
/*** Step 1: load middleware setup - cors,helmet*/
middleware(app);
init();
module.exports = app
```

```
middelware.js
const cors = require("@koa/cors");
const compression = require("koa-compress");
const helmet = require("koa-helmet");
const bodyParser = require("koa-bodyparser");
const sixtyDaysInSeconds = 5184000
function middleware(app) {
  app.use(cors())
  app.use(helmet())
  app.use(helmet.frameguard())
  app.use(helmet.hsts({
    maxAge: sixtyDaysInSeconds
  }))
  app.use(helmet.ieNoOpen())
  app.use(helmet.frameguard({
    action: 'sameorigin'
  }))
  app.use(helmet.noSniff())
  app.use(helmet.referrerPolicy({
    policy: 'same-origin'
  }))
  app.use(helmet.xssFilter())
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(bodyParser()) //koa-body-parser
}
module.exports = middleware;
```

```
route-path.js
const {checkSchema,oneOf} = require("express-validator")
const controller = require("../controller")
function routes(app) {
  app.post("/koatester", controller.validatee(), controller.handler)
}
module.exports = routes
```

```
controller.js
const { header } = require("../../resources/schemas/headers")
const {checkSchema,oneOf} = require("express-validator")
const handler = async function (context) {
  try {    
    let req = context.request
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      context.status = 422
      context.body = errors
      return ctx
    }
    ctx.status= 200
    ctx.body = "SUCCESS"
    return ctx;
  } catch (error) {
    ctx.status= 500
    ctx.body = "INTERNAL FAILURE"
    }
};

**module.exports = () => {
  return async function validatee() {
    [
        checkSchema(header.schema)
    ];  
  }     
}**  
module.exports = { handler }
```

```
headers.js
module.exports = {
    header: {
      schema: {
        name: {
          in: ['headers'],
          exists: true,
          isLength: {
            options: {
              min: 1,
              max: 100
            }
          },
          trim: true,
          errorMessage: 'Invalid name. Please provide valid name'
        },
        id: {
          in: ['headers'],
          exists: true,
          isLength: {
            options: {
              min: 2,
              max: 2
            }
          },
          errorMessage: 'Invalid id. Please provide valid id'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Can someone please explain why the express-validator is throwing the error with koa? But The same code works with express-v4.18.1

Answer (score 0):

in route-path.js you use controller.validatee(), but in controller.js you have this function commented. So that's why you have this error - function is undefined